# How to prove this is a triangulated subcategory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

I'm studying homological algebra. And I'm working on this problem.

> The relation between thick subcategories in $\mathcal{D}$ and localizing classes of morphisms is as follows.
>   A localizing class $S$ in $\operatorname{Mor}(\mathcal{D})$ is said to be *saturated* if
>   \begin{align*}
>       &\, s \in S \\
>   \iff&\, \text{there exist morphisms $f,f'$ in $\mathcal{D}$ such that $f \circ s \in S$ and $s \circ f' \in S$}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Prove the following result.
>   Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a triangulated category.
>   Then
>   $$
>           \mathcal{C}
>   \mapsto \varphi(\mathcal{C})
>   =       \left\{
>             \begin{matrix}
>               \text{$s \in \operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{C}$, $s$ is contained in a distinguished} \\
>               \text{triangle $X \xrightarrow{s} Y \to Z \to X[1]$ with $Z \in \operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{C}$.}
>             \end{matrix}
>           \right\}
> $$
>   determines a one-to-one correspondence between the set of thick subcategories in $\mathcal{D}$ and the set of saturated localizing classes in $\mathcal{D}$ compatible with triangulation.
>
> The converse mapping associates with a class $S \subset \operatorname{Mor} \mathcal{D}$ the full subcategory $\psi(S)$ generated by such objects $Z \in \operatorname{Ob} \mathcal{D}$ that there exists a distinguished triangle $X \xrightarrow{s} Y \to Z \to X[1]$ with $s \in S$.
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXpbf.png)

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a triangulated category. Then there's a bijection between the set of thick subcategories in $\mathcal{D}$ and the set of saturated localizing classes (sometimes called saturated multiplicative system). This is also known for the **Verdier correspondence**.

I've already proved that a thick triangulated subcategory can map to a saturated localizing classes by $\varphi$. But I'm stuck with the converse mapping. That is, if $S$ is a saturated localizing classes, then verify $\psi(S)$ being a thick triangulated subcategory.

**My Effort:** Let $\mathcal{C} = \psi(S)$.

**TS1**: First verify that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma \mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}$. Let $Z \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$, then there's a distinguished triangle 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>s>> Y @>>> Z @>>> \Sigma X
\end{CD}
with $s \in S$. So it suffices to show that $\Sigma^n s \in S$. But I don't know how to do this.

**TS2**: Let 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X @>>> Y @>>> Z @>>> \Sigma X
\end{CD}
be a distinguished triangle. Verify that if $X, Y \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$, then so is $Z$. Actually I'm more confused with this part for I don't know how to use the properties of localizing and saturated.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe Lemma 13.6.6. in the link is what you are looking for. The terminology might seem different. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05RA